# Why the average temperature of the body is taken for finding out temperature difference between body and surrounding?

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

Solution provided in the image,it is mentioned that,the temperature difference between body and surrounding,where the temperature of the body is averaged with two different temperature range,so why is that? As the body is cooling from 70°C to 60°C ,the difference would be 40°C , where I'm going wrong and why the average is taken?

Comment: What is the equation for Newton's law of cooling as you understand it?? Is the solution that is given really correct?

Comment: It is from HC Verma, also ,for similar questions similar solution were mentioned in other books as well (from NCERT and BM Sharma).

Answer (score 0):

The given solution is incorrect.  Newton's law of cooling for this situation reads:  $$\frac{dT}{dt}=-k(T-30)$$ where k is a constant.  The solution to this equation is $$T=30+(T_0-30)e^{-kt}$$where $T_0$ is the initial temperature (70 C).  So, $$60=30+40e^{-5k}$$, and k = 0.0575/min.  The solution they give is k=0,0571/min.

The cumulative time to reach 50 C is given by:  $$50=30+40e^{-0,0575t}$$ which gives 12.05 min.  So the time to cool from 60C to 50 C is 12.05 - 5.0 = 7.05 min.

Comment: The answer given in the book is 7 min. Is the solution given in the book a ' sort of trick '?

Comment: The solution in the book uses a 2nd order accurate central difference finite difference approximation to solve the differential equation.  'for the temperature intervals they considered, their approximation is fairy accurate.

Comment: Why it was used , I mean they could have used normal integration process? What is the significance of this process?

Comment: Like I said, it's a simple and accurate approximation.  I can't read their minds.